# Surfactant concentration from bulk to the interface

Tags: fluid-statics

Is there a theory which describes the transport of surfactant concentration in the bulk of the solution to an interface?

Comment: Yes, and  @John Rennie knows exactly what it is.

Comment: @John Rennie please help.